# Who was the first Super Saiyan to be seen on the TV series?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

I'm looking for the first Super Saiyan that has been seen in the TV series.

As I reminisce, I think Son Goku has been the first we can see transforming fully from Normal to Super Saiyan status (on Namek against Frieza), but I can't remember if there can be seen anyone else being Super Saiyan before. I would count anyone that has these typical features like blonde hair and blue eyes and who is identified as a Super Saiyan in the show. It does not have to be a main character.

**Who was the first?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Son Goku is indeed the very first Super Saiyan to appear in the televised series in a humanoid appearance. He makes the jump to Super Saiyan level one in 'Transformed at Last', the twentieth episode of the Frieza Saga and the ninety-fifth episode in the uncut Dragon Ball Z series. (1991).

> - The Super Saiyan form first premiered in August 1991, within chapter 317 of the Dragon Ball manga, entitled "Life or Death". It also made its anime debut in 1991, first appearing in Dragon Ball Z episode 95, "Transformed at Last". **[Dragon Ball Wiki: Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan)**

The next Super Saiyan seen was Future Trunks who appears in episode 120 and easily utilizes the power to dispatch Frieza and King Cold.

> - The Super Saiyan transformation made its movie debut in the film **[Dragon Ball Z: Cooler's Revenge](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Cooler%27s_Revenge)**. Goku uses his Super Saiyan power to defeat Cooler, Frieza's older and stronger brother, thus finishing off the family. In the concept art drawn by Akira Toriyama for this movie, Super Saiyan Goku has red eyes.

An apocryphal scene was added to the Dragon Ball series, episode 66, **[Goku's New Power](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku%27s_New_Power)**, describing a mythic being called "**[The Original Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Original_Super_Saiyan)**". He was rumored to be little more than a myth of a tailed Saiyan who achieved this legendary status. He appears in the [Golden Great Ape](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Great_Ape) Transformation.

> The Original Super Saiyan (初代の超サイヤ人) was an unnamed Saiyan who could transform into a Super Saiyan. He was originally thought to be nothing more than a myth.

Comment: Actually, Goku isn't the first seen.  When King Kai is telling the story of the Super Saiyan, an image is shown of a Golden Oozaru which King Kai states is the original Super Saiyan.  Goku is actually the second Super Saiyan to be shown, but the first to take on the current appearance.

Comment: I will then mark this answer as right as my question also involves that the shown Super Saiyan has to be identified. In that case, it seems like Goku is the first who showed himself as a SSJ to the audience. I'm also quite sure he was the first to show his willy.

Answer (score 5):

Goku was the first Super Saiyan seen on TV in the battle against Frieza. We know that Broly was a Super Saiyan first, but he does not show up until the movies. There may have been a mention of a legendary Super Saiyan with a faceless Saiyan, but I can't remember if that is from a movie or the show itself.

The original Super Saiyan, notice the gold fur.

[image: Original Super Saiyan]

Comment: You are correct, there is a faceless Super Saiyan in King Kai's story about the Super Saiyan, but he's not in traditional Super Saiyan form, he's in a Golden Oozaru form, i.e. the form Goku and Vegeta take when they transform into SS4's.  Granted, GT is absolute garbage and isn't canon, but the Golden Oozaru is and it's actually considered the true Super Saiyan form.

Comment: Hence why Frieza destroyed the the Saiyen world.

Answer (score 1):

Well before frieza, goku originally went super saiyan fighting lord slug. Hints the name of the movie son goku super saiyan, even the title states it is the first time.

Comment: While the answer could use some flashing out, and the form Son Goku took in the film wasn't what we would now call a Super Sayian it is nontheless a great point - that movie came out 15 episodes before Goku went SSJ on Namek.

Answer (score 0):

Namek saga is the first time of super saiyan but goku was the first super saiyan and the lord slug movie is not cannot but the saiyan form in the movie has 2 different names false super saiyan and pseudo super saiyan

Comment: Could you [edit] this to include evidence to back it up?